# Android Map for Watch - Authentication failed. Timeout while trying to contact the server

Tags: android

I am trying with sample application available @ https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/tree/master/AndroidWearMap

but I am getting time out/authentication failed error all the time. The key which I have used is correct only.

Can anyone help how to implement Map for google watch? or high level architecture is also fine.

Comment: Kindly provide more information. I am facing the same issue.